# How to read multiple records from a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file, `l__cyc.csv`, that contains this:

```
trip_id, time, O_lat, O_lng, D_lat, D_lng
130041910101,1300,51.5841153671,0.134444590094,51.5718053872,0.134878021928
130041910102,1335,51.5718053872,0.134878021928,51.5786920389,0.180940040247
130041910103,1600,51.5786920389,0.180940040247,51.5841153671,0.134444590094
130043110201,1500,51.5712712038,0.138532882664,51.5334949484,0.130489470325
130043110202,1730,51.5334949484,0.130489470325,51.5712712038,0.138532882664
```

And I am trying to pull out separate values, using:

```
with open('./l__cyc.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    origincoords = ['{O_lat},{O_lng}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
with open('./l__cyc.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    trip_id = ['{trip_id}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
with open('./l__cyc.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    destinationcoords = ['{D_lat},{D_lng}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
```

Where `origincoords` should be `51.5841153671, 0.134444590094`,
`trip_id` should be `130041910101`, and `destinationcoords` should be
`51.5718053872, 0.134878021928`.

However, I get a `KeyError`:

```
KeyError: 'O_lat'
```

Is this something simple and there's something fundamental I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just avoid the space between headers

```
trip_id,time,O_lat,O_lng,D_lat,D_lng
```

**OR**

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Error persists

Comment: Works for me.   Note that there must be no trailing space after D_lng, as well.   The code pasted above (in the question) has a space after D_lng.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you get the key error, because the key does not exist in your dictionary.

Next, I would advise against running through the file 3 times, when you can do it a single time!

For me it worked, when I added the fieldnames to the reader.

```
import csv
from cStringIO import StringIO

src = """trip_id, time, O_lat, O_lng, D_lat, D_lng
130041910101,1300,51.5841153671,0.134444590094,51.5718053872,0.134878021928
130041910102,1335,51.5718053872,0.134878021928,51.5786920389,0.180940040247
130041910103,1600,51.5786920389,0.180940040247,51.5841153671,0.134444590094
130043110201,1500,51.5712712038,0.138532882664,51.5334949484,0.130489470325
130043110202,1730,51.5334949484,0.130489470325,51.5712712038,0.138532882664
"""
f = StringIO(src)

# determine the fieldnames
fieldnames= "trip_id,time,O_lat,O_lng,D_lat,D_lng".split(",")

# read the file
reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

# storage
origincoords = []
trip_id = []
destinationcoords = []

# iterate the rows
for row in reader:
    origincoords.append('{O_lat},{O_lng}'.format(**row))
    trip_id.append('{trip_id}'.format(**row))
    destinationcoords.append('{D_lat},{D_lng}'.format(**row))

# pop the header off the list
origincoords.pop(0)
trip_id.pop(0)
destinationcoords.pop(0)

# show the result
print origincoords
print trip_id
print destinationcoords
```

I don't really know what you are trying to achieve there, but I'm sure there is a better way of doing it!

Comment: Thanks @enpenax. You're right, three iterations is unnecessary. Many thanks for your code & the helpful comments. Im learning ;)